# Starting a new Activity from a fragment with Floating action button

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

I am currently trying to start a new activity called FoodJournalEntry from the click of a floating action button in a fragment called FoodJournalFragment (a fragment of my MainActivity.java activity). However, although I am getting no errors, my setOnClickListener function isn't doing anything. The id of the floating action button is "fab". Please help!

here is the code i have right now. I am trying to get the Toast thing to display some sort of message so I can tell if the button is even working, but literally nothing is happening. I do see the logcat recognizing the click i think but that's it.

The code I am writing inside of the onCreateView in the fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homepage, container, false);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FoodJournalEntry.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    });

    return v;
}
```

XML file for fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id ="@+id/tasksText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Tasks"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textSize="32sp"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/tasksRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tasksText"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your title mentions "starting an activity" but your question seems to be about "clicking a button". I assume that eventually you want to start an activity when the user clicks the button, but are not even sure that your click handler works yet, right? If that is the case, then your question title should be about the button clicking part. We can address starting another activity later. You should also strip down your code to only focus on the button clicking. For example, the second activity isn't relevant yet, so you can remove it from the question here.

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstand...which Toast are you trying to see that doesn't show up? You have two of them in the code you show here. This is another example where you should simplify the code you post here to focus on your exact question.

Comment: I have made some changes to my question to focus more on the button part. To my knowledge though, i only have on Toast message which is in the java file. I am honestly not sure if the button is working or not so that's just sth I pointed out in the post. I hope this simplifies my question. @Code-Apprentice

Comment: When I click on the floating action button, my logcat sends some version of the following message:
2022-03-28 11:59:12.480 5018-5043/com.example.foodjournalproject D/EGL_emulation: app_time_stats: avg=14.66ms min=2.32ms max=121.17ms count=55
Not entirely sure what it means but its not in red so it should be fine? The toast message doesn't come up though, nor does it open the new activity like how I've programmed it to do. @Code-Apprentice

Comment: fab click listener put in the `onViewCreated`